# remove micropython from esp and install esp32 firmwae

Tags: esp32, micropython, firmware

i have a esp32 and afew month ago i installed micropython on it , now after erase_flash it with

```
python3 esptool.py erase_flash
```

and now when i want to run a simple

```
Serial.print("hellow world");
```

it pop up this

> 20:44:12.356 -> Th�l���ES%���"D��$DD$ZI$DD$�#"DD�ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
> 20:44:20.138 ->
> 20:44:20.138 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
> 20:44:20.138 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
> 20:44:20.139 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
> 20:44:20.139 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
> 20:44:20.139 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1184

and also while uploading new script it syays

> Sketch uses 259173 bytes (19%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
> Global variables use 22352 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 305328 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
> esptool.py v4.5.1
> Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
> Connecting.....
> Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision v3.0)
> Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
> Crystal is 40MHz
> MAC: c8:f0:9e:52:c8:24
> Uploading stub...
> Running stub...
> Stub running...
> Configuring flash size...
> Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
> Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
> Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
> Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x0004ffff...
> Compressed 18928 bytes to 13069...
> Writing at 0x00001000... (100 %)
> Wrote 18928 bytes (13069 compressed) at 0x00001000 in 1.4 seconds (effective 109.2 kbit/s)...
> Hash of data verified.
> Compressed 3072 bytes to 146...
> Writing at 0x00008000... (100 %)
> Wrote 3072 bytes (146 compressed) at 0x00008000 in 0.1 seconds (effective 431.5 kbit/s)...
> Hash of data verified.
> Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...
> Writing at 0x0000e000... (100 %)
> Wrote 8192 bytes (47 compressed) at 0x0000e000 in 0.1 seconds (effective 720.1 kbit/s)...
> Hash of data verified.
> Compressed 259536 bytes to 144032...
> Writing at 0x00010000... (11 %)
> Writing at 0x0001d7a2... (22 %)
> Writing at 0x00024e03... (33 %)
> Writing at 0x0002a183... (44 %)
> Writing at 0x0002f508... (55 %)
> Writing at 0x00035751... (66 %)
> Writing at 0x0003fd9a... (77 %)
> Writing at 0x00045941... (88 %)
> Writing at 0x0004ae7d... (100 %)
> Wrote 259536 bytes (144032 compressed) at 0x00010000 in 12.8 seconds (effective 161.7 kbit/s)...
> Hash of data verified.
>
> Leaving...
> Hard resetting via RTS pin...

i want to recovry my esp32 like a first time when the had a wifi and bluetooth service on it

Comment: It's unnecessary to "remove MicroPython firmware". The act of flashing an Arduino program copies over it. You're getting a watchdog timer reset. Please edit the question to include the full program you're trying to flash - preferably a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't tell what you're doing if you don't include the actual program.